# Github branch protection forces pull request main to stage

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

We've setup branch protection on the branch `main`. Our developers merge to `stage` which is regularly merged into the `main` branch. Every time we do that GitHub suggests a `new Pull Request` from `main` to `stage` after each succesful merge. This seems a bit odd as the changes on `stage` where just merged into `main`. Why is this?

We've set the `stage` as Default branch and `main` as protected branch.

An example:
[image]

This is what GitHub suggest:
[image]

But main only differst because changes from stages where merged rendering `main` and `stage` identical.

Comment: What is the default branch in your repository? https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Comment: Please don’t write edit-edits - write for new readers [reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685/761202)

Comment: If GitHub is suggesting a merge, there is history in main that is not in stagea. Please edit the question to show enough history for both branches to be able to write an answer.

Comment: Sorry @tjarbo my edit and you question crossed. But `stage` is default and we pull to `main` only from `stage` and as `main` is protected I wonder why `stage` could be behind `main`.